# Panorama page in landscape mode

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, orientation, panorama-control

In my new app, there is a windows phone panorama page. I thought it would be best to enable both Landscape and Portrait orientation. But in Landscape, 40% or the screen space is occupied by the heading, 20% by the sub-heading and only the rest stays for the content.

So my question is: should I disable Landscape mode, let everything as it is or change the design and make e. g. the heading smaller?

I know I can put my content in a ScrollViewer, but it still looks a bit silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Landscape mode should be disabled for Panorama Control. From [Panorama control design guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windowsphone/design/hh202912%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

> The Panorama control is portrait orientation only. There is no landscape support for the Panorama control. Dialogs launched from within the Panorama control shouldn’t be rotated to avoid jarring experiences.